# What functions satisfy the functional equation $f(x)-g(x)=f\big(g(x)\big)$?

Tags: special-functions, functional-equations

How could I find an $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that satisfy this?
$$f(x)-g(x)=f\big(g(x)\big)$$

Comment: Do you want *a* solution or all the solutions?

Comment: Trivial solution: Let f(x)=g(x)=0 for all x

Comment: its like recursive function , let f(g(x))=f(x)-g(x)  then f(x)=f(g(x))-x

Comment: Interesting, I came about this formula looking at the Lambert W function and came to this as $ \large \ln x - W(x) = \ln (W(x))$ so I am sort of interested that there are other possibilities that are just polynomials as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may be useful to rearrange your equation as $$f(x)=g(x) + f(g(x)).\tag1$$  By taking this as the definition of $f$ and applying it repeatedly to the right-hand side, we get $$f(x) = g(x) + g(g(x)) + g(g(g(x))) + \dotsb = \sum_{k=1}^\infty g^{(k)}(x).\tag2$$ Thus, for any function $g$, we can obtain a corresponding $f$ by summing the [iterates](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) of $g$, provided that this sum converges.

A necessary (but not sufficient) condition for convergence of the sum is that the orbit of any starting point $x$, under the repeated application of $g$, must eventually tend to zero.  In particular, $g$ must not have any fixed points other than 0, and must not have any cycles or other non-point attractors.

Alas, this method does *not* generate all possible solutions.  A counterexample, [provided by barak manos](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/936296), is $g(x) = 0$, for which $f(x) = a$ satisfies equation $(1)$ for any $a \in \mathbb R$, even though equation $(2)$ yields only the solution $f(x) = 0$.

(In fact, it's easy to show that, if $g$ and $f$ satisfy equation $(1)$, then so do $g$ and $f+c$ for any constant $c$.  Thus, if equation $(1)$ has any solution for some $g$, it must have an infinite family of solutions differing by a constant term added to $f$.)

Similarly, for $g(x) = bx$, the series $(2)$ converges to $f(x) = \frac{b}{1-b}x$ only when $|b| < 1$, even though this choice of $f(x)$ actually yields a valid solution to equation $(1)$ for any $b \ne 1$.  However, it may sometimes be possible to apply more powerful [summation methods](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_method) to obtain formal solutions even for some functions $g$ for which this series diverges.

Comment: +1 Such a simple rearrangement leading to such a clear definition

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

Try $f(x)=ax$ and $g(x)=bx$ and find out what values of $a,b$ will do.

Comment: That does not show that those are all the solutions. Still, a +1 from me since OP is asking for *a* solution, not *all* solutions.

Answer (score 4):

For polynomial degree $0$:

- $f(x)=a$
- $g(x)=b$
- $f(g(x))=f(b)=a$
- $f(x)-g(x)=a-b$
- $f(g(x))=f(x)-g(x) \implies a=a-b \implies b=0$
- So you can choose $[f(x)=a]$ and $[g(x)=0]$ for any $[a\in\mathbb{R}]$

For polynomial degree $1$:

- $f(x)=ax$
- $g(x)=bx$
- $f(g(x))=f(bx)=abx$
- $f(x)-g(x)=ax-bx$
- $f(g(x))=f(x)-g(x) \implies abx=ax-bx \implies b=\frac{a}{a+1}$
- So you can choose $[f(x)=ax]$ and $[g(x)=\frac{ax}{a+1}]$ for any $[a\in\mathbb{R},a\neq-1]$

Answer (score 0):

For polynomial degree 2:

- $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, $g(x)=x+d$

Substitute and find values for $a,b,c,d$